# Can Superman see through his eyelids?

Tags: dc, superman, powers

Given that his x-ray vision allows him to see though skin, can he use this ability with his eyes closed? Or do they prevent it somehow?

Comment: It's the old "Can God create a rock so big not even he can lift?" question... Sure he has X-Ray vision, but he also has super skin!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Probably yes

How Superman X-ray vision works varies from comic to comic, but there is a feat that could prove that indeed it is possible for Superman to see through his eyelids: a Kryptonian seeing through​ his own skin.

Below you can see a picture (*Supergirl* #2 - actually I got the it from a Google images​ search that linked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/is-superman-really-super-compared-to-other-kryptonians), so thanks) that shows Supergirl being able to see her own bones through her skin.

[image: Supergirl discovers her x-ray vision]

Would this cause Superman to be unable to sleep? Thankfully for him it's been shown repeatedly that he needs to purposely activate his power.

[image: Superman uses his x-ray vision]

Comment: I have a vague recollection of having occasionally seen Superman use his X-Ray vision to check for broken bones, cellular damage, etc., in his own body or in other Kryptonian bodies. Some of that going back to "Pre-Crisis" (i.e. pre-1986) comic books, *I think.* But I've having trouble remembering exactly when and where I read those scenes. But I agree with you in principle -- I've read a lot of Superman comics, and I've never gotten the impression that his own flesh qualifies as "X-Ray-vision-proof!"

Comment: I just realized something. Why would she put her face in her hands right then? If the problem is she can see through her fingers, why shove them up to her face? Now I'm wondering if her eyelids actually **do** block the power and prevented her from seeing her own bones.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd seems like the instinctive movement to do, even if it doesn't work

Comment: @Ram Instinctive, yes, but shouldn't she have pulled away if she had noticed it wasn't helping? Given her initial reaction, I'd assume so. I suppose it could've been a mental thing, like she was so disturbed by the image of her hands that she was able to quickly turn the power off (like the next panel suggests), but do we know how much time is between those two panels? Both Supes are in totally different positions, which could take at least a few seconds (longer if they're being dramatic), and her power isn't **starting** to fade until she's on the ground.

Comment: TL;DR I don't think I'm convinced they **don't** block the power somehow afterall