# Which DC Heroine has the Greatest Physical Strength?

Tags: dc, super-hero

I realize that Wonder Woman is easily the most represented of DC's super ladies. And yes, she is, according to many sources, one of the best hand-to-hand combatants out there and more than physically capable. However, I am curious about pure brute strength.

- I am not looking for those who are capable of magically infusing themselves with strength, or have cosmic powers that would make their power infinite in nature.
- The Strength must be physical in nature, not psychic
- The strength must also come from themselves, not an object that they wield.

I am perfectly fine with including information from any and all of the DC multiverse, comics, live action films, and the animated films.

Comment: I would guess Supergirl, being roughly equal to Superman, but I dunno if there are any cosmic-level women superheroes.

Comment: Not a bad point, but I wondered if Big Barbara or Amethyst were anywhere near that.

Comment: http://static2.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/9/98379/2106476-wonder_woman_v3_41_012.jpg - Wonder Woman, Power Girl, [Supergirl](http://static3.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/11/114405/2899107-supergirl_17_010.jpg) are all basically on a par with each other. In the modern continuity, they're all just about as strong as Superman (note that Wonder Woman and Superman are both classed as "strength A-1"; http://tinyurl.com/zos52cz + http://tinyurl.com/hluf4mu by Star Labs

Comment: Well, it's star labs, I'm not going to argue with that.

Comment: I don't know why this is getting downvoted, sorry. This, to me, is an interesting question that should be objective, given that max-weight lifted stats or incidents are available through the comics. My only critique is that you narrow it down to non-cosmic-level heroines such as Death. Some of them could just have arbitrary levels of infinite strength.

Comment: I don't either. I mean, I hear this question posed for other super powers/characters (who is faster, the Flash or Superman ect) and while my knee jerk thought IS Diana Prince but I always thought that part of her physical ability was her skills as a warrior, not just brute power.

Comment: In which universe?  There's at least 52, and I'm sure the answer differs between them.  It's also very difficult to tell who has magically-infused strength vs physical strength.  This can also change per writer - Superman (who is traditionally very physically strong) was written for a while as having a telekinetic field he extended to things he touched (meaning it wasn't 'physical strength' by your limits).  Also, considering the New Gods are a thing, the lines blur at high strength levels.

Answer (score 6):

### There doesn't appear to be a general consensus.

You can find lots of lists of strength levels for DC characters, and usually Wonder Woman is at the top, or Power Girl is, or Super Girl.

Here are a few examples.

In this ranking of [Strongest DC Superheroes](https://www.cbr.com/strongest-dc-superheroes-ranked/), you see this ranking (excluding men).

1. Power Girl
2. Wonder Woman
3. Super Girl
4. Donna Troy
5. Mary Marvel
6. Big Barda
7. Wonder Girl

In [another list](http://misc.thefullwiki.org/Strength_Scale) spanning the multiverse, grouping them by categories of strength, you see the same people, although they are not ranked, all have "potentially incalculable (able to lift far in excess of 100 tons)".

As Valorum [pointed out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139034/which-dc-heroine-has-the-greatest-physical-strength#comment352375_139034), Wonder Woman considers Power Girl to be at least her equal in strength and speed (in that continuity).

And then in Superman/Batman: Apocalypse Super Girl is considered to be potentially more powerful than Superman. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6028/1148

Unless DC definitively comes out with a list of "strongest to weakest" we may never know the truth, since all heroes and villains powers are victims of plot device.

Comment: Note: There are two "Power Girl" characters now. I assume this is talking about the original, the one who is usually another dimension's Supergirl, but who was tied to Atlantis and Arion as the explanation for her powers for a while, post-Crisis on Infinite Earths

Answer (score 0):

I would rate them this way:

1. Supergirl. As a Kryptonian she has all the powers of Superman!
2. Mary Marvel. This depends on which Mary, pre crisis or the the post crisis Mary who had Black Adam's powers...
3. Power Girl. Alternate Supergirl, but still a Kryptonian minus the Kryptonite weakness.
4. Wonder Woman
5. Donna Troy (Wonder Woman 2)
6. Maxima
7. Big Barda
8. Starfire
9. Terra

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What basis do you have for this order?  Can you provide any evidence, or is it just your opinion?